# What is an efficient to find if a given sub sequence exists in an infinite sequence?

Tags: sequence, matching, parity

There is an infinite sequence b, such that b[i] = 1 , if the binary representation of i has odd number of 1s, and b[i] = 0 , otherwise.
Given a sub sequence of 0s and 1s, I am required to find the starting index of a match, if one exists or state that a match doesn't exist if it doesn't.
What is an efficient way to do it?

Comment: The "number of ones" is also known as the "Hamming weight".

Comment: Okay, anyone knows how to solve it? I still haven't got a method to solve it, let alone find an efficient solution.